# Rounded corners in MS IE 7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

How do I get rounded corners in MSIE7?  (and cross-browser, as a bonus, but IE7 is vital)

Can I do it without extra images?

Do I need a bunch of images for different text box/table sizes?

---

Update:  This is actually important, now that I think of it ...

What if I am generating my HTML from PHP and it can be dynamic, so I can't really know the size?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd recommend using CSS3 styling and then [CSS3PIE](http://css3pie.com). Works like a charm!

Comment: PIE is awesome, and guess what Mawg - it works in IE6-8 and handles a lot more than just rounded corners. Highly recommend.

Comment: Do! It even provides the CSS for you (you need to check the 'show CSS' box though).

Comment: errm, it's not too clear ... does that scale? it seems not. Looks like I nee dto use my PHP to decide on approx size & choose from a multiple of images

Comment: @Mawg - CSS3Pie creates the rounded corners using vector graphics, so it scales perfectly, and no images at all. It is by far the best solution available for rounded corners in IE7/8. It does still have issues, but they're all caused by issues in IE which will affect other solutions as well (see the website for more info).

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Ian's answer, one possibility is to use CSS3's border-radius, then include [CurvyCorners](http://code.google.com/p/curvycorners/). You can do it without images -- that is, you don't need to provide images to make either of the solutions mentioned here work.

Answer (score 1):

You can have CSS round corners on any element of any width/height. There are numerous solutions/workarounds for IE. Some require JavaScript. Some use VML wrapped in .htc files. Some use multiple images. Numerous techniques are discussed here:

1. [CSS-Discuss - Rounded Corners](http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Rounded_Corners)
2. [CSS Rounded Corners 'Roundup'](http://www.smileycat.com/miaow/archives/000044.php) -- recommended reading