# Rounded corners in MS IE 7 - on Intranet with no access to the outside world - and no JS/HTC

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, rounded-corners

I got a good answer to my previous question [Rounded corners in MS IE 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6160559/rounded-corners-in-ms-ie-7) ...

it was my own stupid fault for forgetting to mention that it is for an intranet which can't access the outside world, and that JS is forbidden, so I can't use HTC.

So, here's the question again.. Can I (and, if so, what's the simplest way to) get (scalable) rounded corners in MS IE 7+ using only CSS/HTML ... images are ok, but I worry about the user resizing the browser.  A bonus if it's cross-browser, but IE7+ with no JS/HTC suffices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to do it -

SpiffyCorners - http://spiffycorners.com/

With images - http://modxcms.com/about/team/rthrash/simple-rounded-corner-css-boxes.html

MS VML - http://www.notgeeklycorrect.com/web-development/2010/01/21/easy-rounded-corners-working-in-ie7ie8

Google around there are tons of ways to do this without CSS3.

Comment: +1 looks good, thanks. I am slowly working my way through them. I want to wrap a table in a box with rounded corners, but displaying Spiffy is displaying at 100% width for some reason ...  any idea how I get it to just cover the table?

Comment: You'll need to set the width of the outermost containing DIV, by default it's a block level element.