# Css curved corners - ie7+

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, border

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rounded corners in MS IE 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6160559/rounded-corners-in-ms-ie-7)

I think I know the main idea of how to accomplish rounded corners w/o javascript. But generally the problem wasn't so difficult, since my outside color (the color outside the border) was solid. But on this design, the background behind the curved border is a gradient.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Also: [Rounded corners in MS IE 7 - on Intranet with no access to the outside world - and no JS/HTC](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6181695)

Comment: Have a look at http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/.